# Do we have rest mass according to quantum physics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, mass

I know wave must be in motion and resonant waves are actually in motion. So I don't understand what is a rest mass of a particle. If a particle is just a wave in a particular field, it should be moving and it can't be in stationary state. So there is nothing that we can call rest mass for particles.

Comment: A particle's rest mass is just (proportional to) the (potential) energy in the rest system in which the momentum is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends in the context you are considering. There are two aspects to think about:

- the theoretical definition, which depends on a model, an image of reality
- the operational definition: the way you measure it.

Rest mass is a concept from Relativity, which is a part of classical physics. Here, we can think of particles as points of mass, with no wave properties. In this case, the rest mass of a particle can be measured by accelerating it from rest (in your frame) and using $F = ma$ to get a value for $m$. The way you measure it in practice is by weighing it, assuming that thermal motion (the jiggling from the heat) is low enough that what you are measuring is indeed the rest mass. For now, there are no waves in the picture.

Even for radioactivity it works: When people starting studying radioactivity, they discovered that when an element decays into another element, it releases an amount of energy proportional to the difference in rest mass. Even if you know nuclei are not exactly point particles, they are close enough for us to use the *operational* definition of rest mass from special relativity. This also works in particle collisions!

Now, when you think of particles as waves in the fields, you are entering a more subtle realm, and as you say, there is nothing really at rest there. The role *mass* plays in this picture is more arbitrary, appearing as a constant in the equations and not as the property of some *thing* that at rest.
But in some cases it is still appropriate to use the concept of rest mass.